# telegrambot answerCallbackQuery using getupdatecli.php method , show_alert not wroking

Tags: telegram-bot

```
function check_user_balance($chatId,$callbackQuery){

    $response = \Longman\TelegramBot\Request::answerCallbackQuery([
        'callback_query_id' => $callbackQuery->getId(),
        'text' => "test get user balance",
        'show_alert' => 1, // Set this to true to show the response as a popup
    ]);
    if ($response->isOk()) {
        // Get the array of ChatMember objects
        $result = $response->getResult();
        print_r("SEND");
    } else {
        // Handle the error
        $error_message = $response->getDescription();
        echo "Error: $error_message\n";
    }
}

$server_response = $telegram->handleGetUpdates();

if ($server_response->isOk()) {
    foreach ($server_response->getResult() as $update) {
        if ($update->getCallbackQuery()) {
            $callbackQuery = $update->getCallbackQuery();
            $callbackData = $callbackQuery->getData();
            $chatId = $callbackQuery->getMessage()->getChat()->getId();
            // die(var_dump($update->getCallbackQuery()));
            // Perform the balance check and send the response
            check_user_balance($chatId, $callbackQuery);
        }
    }

}
```

the die(vardump) part is getting the response as i click , the check_user_balance function also echoing "SEND", however when i click on the telegram the alert just not showing , also changed the show_alert => true , the reponse is the same.

```
$result = $response->getResult();
print_r($result);
```

i getting 1 as response from the above code.